# What would you call a speech introducing an honoring ceremony for highest-ranking graduating students?

Tags: meaning, phrase-request

Suppose I am a college president and I'm preparing a speech to deliver in honor of the graduates who came top of their graduating class. After the speech, there's going to be a celebration and the students will step forward and receive medals. What should I call this speech? I'm thinking:

> Valedictorians honoring ceremony speech

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason to give a speech a name is so you can have something to write in the program. If I were giving a speech of this type, I would put one of the following in the program:

- Awards Presentation
- Presentation of Academic Awards
- Recognition of Academic Achievement
- Recognition of Valedictorians
- Presentation of Academic Honors

There are a few combinations of that you might try. Note that there is only one valedictorian (or perhaps one per school if you are at the university level). If you are talking about a larger group, such as all those achieving *summa cum laude* you would not use that word.

Also note that "honors" is often a specific program at a university, so you might shy away from this unless you are referring to this particular program.

Comment: Yes, it's a larger group. Specifically, a group of 10 students with the highest GPA. I would like the speech title to include a reference to "those who are first in class" but I can't find one word for that.